# Run local script with local input file on remote host

Tags: shell-script, ssh, io-redirection, stdin

I have a local script that I want to run on several remote servers. The command syntax I'm using is:

```
ssh <remote_server> "bash -s" < ./local_script.sh
```

This works fine, and even lets me pass parameters to *local_script.sh*. However, I'd really like to pass an input file to it, as in:

```
local_script.sh < local_file.txt
```

Combining these two statements gives:

```
ssh <remote_server> "bash -s" < ./local_script.sh < local_file.txt
```

When I run this, I get

```
bash: line 1: FOO: command not found
bash: line 2: BAR: command not found
bash: line 3: BAZ: command not found
...
```

where FOO, BAR, BAZ, etc. are the first word on each line of *local_file.txt*:

```
FOO     FOO_PARAM1
BAR     BAR_PARAM1
BAZ     BAZ_PARAM2
...
```

So, it looks like `"bash -s"` on the remote server is interpreting *local_file.txt* as a script file, instead of an input file to *local_script.sh*. Is there any way to fix this (other than creating a wrapper script)?

Answer (score 8):

While `ssh` provides for two separate output streams (for stdout and stderr), it only feeds one input stream (stdin). So you'd need either to pass the script content and input file via different mechanisms.

For instance, one via a variable, one via stdin:

```
LC_CODE=$(cat local_script.sh) ssh host 'eval "$LC_CODE"' < input
```

(assuming both your `ssh` client passes the `LC_*` variable (`SendEnv` in `ssh_config`) and the `sshd` server accepts them (`AcceptEnv` in `sshd_config`))

Or simply pass the content of the `local_script.sh` as the remote shell code assuming the login shell of the remote user is the right one for the syntax of that script:

```
ssh host "$(cat local_script.sh)" < input
```

Or concatenate the code and input fed to `ssh`'s stdin like with:

```
{
  echo '{'; cat local_script.sh; echo '}; exit'
  cat input
} | ssh host 'bash -s some arguments'
```

Here using `bash` because `bash` will take care of reading the input one byte at a time so as not to read past that `}; exit` line while not all other shells do that.

Or if `sed` on the remote host is GNU `sed`:

```
echo '#END-OF-SCRIPT' | cat local_script.sh - input |
  ssh host 'set some arguments; eval "$(sed -u "/^#END-OF-SCRIPT/q")"'
```

(here having the code evaluated by the login shell of the remote user and assuming it's Bourne-like)

Comment: The second example `ssh host "$(cat local_script.sh)" < input` worked great, and is an elegant solution as well. Thanks!

Comment: From the Bash manual: "The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`."

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more elegant solution using the BASH 'here-strings' operator ('<<<')

```bsh
ssh -t host "/bin/bash <(base64 --decode <<<'$(base64 < script)' )"
```

IT takes the script, converts it to a base64 string, in the SSH command it converts it back and gives it to the bash as a pipe-filename.

For an script to ste up an interactive shell prefix the 'pipe filename' with "--rcfile"

```bsh
ssh -t host "/bin/bash --rcfile <(base64 --decode <<<'$(base64 < script)' )"
```

More on...
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/apps/ssh_remote_commands.txt

Answer (score 1):

This works well and even lets you pass the contents of multiple files to the script:

```
ssh host "bash -s -- '$(cat local_file_1.txt)'  '$(cat local_file_2.txt)'" < local_script.sh
```

The explanation is that `ssh` will execute `bash -s` on login with the script arguments being everything after `--`. So `$1` will be the contents of `local_file_1.txt` and `$2` will be the contents of `local_file_2.txt`. `bash -s` reads commands from stdin which comes from `< local_script.sh`.